# Why is Graphical layout different in eclipse vs real device

Tags: eclipse, android-layout

I have noted some times the XML in graphical layout displays differently form the same XML on a emulator and real device

In this case I have a imageview wrapped in a linearlayout perfectly centred in graphical layout but positioned to left in emulator/device and another image spanning the width of the layout in graphical layout  but falling short on emulator/device.

Is there a reason for this or away to avoid it.

Comment: It's just an emulator, after all.  So it's not going to be perfect.  But it does give a very good representation.  But then, you have to match your AVD to the exact specs of your physical device.  Even then, use things like "dp" rather than "px" for most things, for a start.

Comment: I needed to set the emulator type i was looking for in the drop down menu of the graphical layout , makes more sense now.